# How to limit the CSS only affected in a particular npm package?

Tags: node.js, blueprint-css, blueprintjs

Here is a npm package I am using:
http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#components.usage

I would like to use their component with CSS, but I don't their CSS affect to my own CSS. Is this possible to allow the CSS package ONLY affected in that npm components? Thanks.

Comment: There's not really an automatic way. However, from a *very* cursory scan of their doc, it seems like they may use `pt-*` as their pseudo "namespace" so you may not find any actual CSS conflicts (provided you haven't prefixed all your classes with `pt-`.

Answer (score 2):

Precisely what @barry-johnson said in his comment above: we use `pt-` as a namespace for all of our CSS classes to avoid collisions with your own application styles. For instance, you could use your own `.custom-button` alongside our `.pt-button` with no conflicts.

However, if you use a Blueprint React component, then it's going to use the Blueprint classes, and you're going to want to use our CSS (because it's not just pretty colors, there's some useful layout stuff in there too). Hope that helps!